# Django. Как отправить действие во views.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-template

**Входные данные:**

Имеется сайт на `Django`. Одна из `template` содержит 20 кнопок для обнуления некоторых данных в базе данных. Пользуются данной страницей не часто и то только избранные, поэтому вопроса о логичности данного решения я не ставлю. Каждая кнопка уникальна и при нажатии пересылает некоторые данные во `views.py` (назовем их `регистр` и `состояние`).

**Как работает сейчас**

Каждая кнопка оборачивается в `<form action="" method="post"></form>` и содержит скрытые `input`, которые содержат необходимые флаги для манипуляций на стороне сервера и БД. Во `views.py` смотрятся какие `регистр` и `состояние` пришли из `template`  и по флагу направляется в одну из веток `if`, и относительно этого строятся запросы к БД и логика поведения.

**Что не так**

При нажатии на любую кнопку во `views.py` летят все `input`, `csrf`-токены и прочий не нужный мусор.

**Вопрос**

Есть ли решение, которое позволяет одназначно определить нажатие кнопки для метода `POST`, чтобы не затрагивать всю информацию со страницы, а получить один токен и одну пару `регистр`:`состояние`? Плюс избежать загромождающую логику во `views.py`, которая содержит "миллион" `if`-ов

В решениях на *SO* примеры почти все одинаковые и реализовано как описано выше в пункте **"Как работает сейчас"**

Comment: csrf - не мусор ;)

Comment: @Jack_oS когда их 20, то сложно другое слово найти =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте для каждой кнопки свой метод во views.py:

```
def action1(request):
  ...

def action2(request):
  ...
```

Добавьте их в urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^existing/path/action1', views.action1),
    url(r'^existing/path/action2', views.action2),
    ...
]
```

При заворачивании кнопки в форму задавайте `action` и необходимые для действия параметры:

```
<form action="action1" method="post">
  ... тут только параметры для action1
</form>
```

Comment: Да, это рабочий вариант. Но 20 функций во `views.py`? Хм... Ладно, `patterns` для урлов можно прогнать через цикл и возвращать набор из двацати. В самом `template` эти двадцать форм так и будут висеть. Надо попробовать, выглядит не плохо

Comment: Не понятно, что вы ожидаете. Одну функцию с if-ами не хотите, 20 функций тоже. Как тогда может выглядеть на уровне обработчиков приемлимый вариант? Где-то же должна быть диспечеризация.

Comment: это так, размышления вслух. На самом деле я написал функцию по созданию этих двадацти функций, создание урлов тоже функция на 4 строки. Все круто, спасибо, за идею. Как это будет работать посмотрю уже завтра